# Union of locally finite family of co-zero sets is co-zero set

Tags: general-topology

It's not true that any union of co-zero sets is also co-zero, but it is true for locally finite family. Please, help me to proove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ be a locally finite family of cozero sets. For each $i \in I$ choose $f_i: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ continuous such that $U_i = f_i^{-1}(]0,1])$.
Define $f: X \rightarrow {\bf R}, f(x) := \sum_{i \in I} f_i(x)$.

Show that $f$ is well-defined, continuous and that $f^{-1}({\bf R}^{> 0}) = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$.